# Error: Property or method "users" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I am having issues displaying the data that I stored inside my Firebase database collection. 
Originally I was getting the error *"Function CollectionReference.doc() requires its first argument to be of type non-empty string, but it was: undefined"*
I was able to fix this problem by providing the correct path in the router configuration file, but now I am getting the error:
**Property or method "users" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render**

The code

```
    <template>
    <div class="profile container">
        <h2 class="deep-purple-text center">Your information</h2>
                <div class="card-content">
                    <ul class="info">
                        <li v-for="(user, index) in users" :key="index">
                            <p>{{ profile.name }}</p>
                        </li>
                        <li v-for="(user, index) in users" :key="index">
                            <p>{{ profile.address }}</p>
                        </li>
                        <li v-for="(user, index) in users" :key="index">
                            <p>{{ profile.zip }}</p>
                        </li>
                        <li v-for="(user, index) in users" :key="index">
                            <p>{{ profile.phone }}</p>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
        </div>
    </template>
    <script>
    import db from '@/firebase/init'
    import firebase from 'firebase'
    export default {
        data(){
            return{
                profile: null,


            }
        },
 created(){
    let user = firebase.auth().currentUser 
    db.firestore().collection('users').where('user_id', '==', user.uid).get()
    .then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                this.profile = doc.data()
            })
        })
      }
    }
    </script>
```

Here is my router configuration as requested by another user.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Index from '@/components/Index'
import AddProduct from '@/components/AddProduct'
import EditProduct from '@/components/EditProduct'
import Signup from '@/components/Signup'
import Login from '@/components/Login'
import Userinfo from '@/components/Userinfo'
import firebase from 'firebase'

Vue.use(Router)

const router = new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Index',
      component: Index,
    },
    {
      path: '/add-product',
      name: 'AddProduct',
      component: AddProduct,
    },
    {
      path: '/edit-product/:product_slug',
      name: 'EditProduct',
      component: EditProduct,
    },
    {
      path: '/signup',
      name: 'Signup',
      component: Signup
    },
    {
      path: '/login',
      name: 'Login',
      component: Login
    },
    {
      path: '/profile',
      name: 'Userinfo',
      component: Userinfo,
    }
  ]
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if(to.matched.some(rec => rec.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    let user = firebase.auth().currentUser
    if(user){
      next()
    } else{
      next({ name: 'Login' })
    }
  } else{
    next()
  }
})
export default router
```

Comment: It seems that `this.$route.params.id` is undefined.

Comment: How and where should I define it?

Comment: Normally, if you have correctly configured your router, it comes from the path used to call the application page. Can you add to your question your router configuration (edit the question via the edit link above)?

Comment: I added the router configuration. Thank you =)

Comment: I also edited the "Create" part. It still does not work, but at least I think I am on the right track.

Comment: "It still does not work"? Which problem do you have? For the `this.$route.params.id`, it is normal that you get `undefined`: nowhere in your router config you define a corresponding  path/route. See https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html

Comment: Sorry I thought I had written it in my edit, but I was too quick. My apologies The problem now is that when my user log in and go to the userinfo page, it is blank (it is supposed to show the user data I entered when signing in). In the console log on the userinfo page I am now getting the error "property or method "users" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render"

Comment: I edited the original question. Now it should make more sense. Again sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having corrected the problem with the router configuration, you now have the following error:

> Property or method "users" is not defined on the instance but
>   referenced during render

This is because, in the template you refer to `users` but this property is not declared in the `data` object in the script.

You should do as follows:

```
export default {
 data(){
     return{
        users: []
     }
 },
 created(){
    let user = firebase.auth().currentUser 
    db.firestore().collection('users').where('user_id', '==', user.uid).get()
    .then(snapshot => {
        let usersArray = [];
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
             usersArray.push(doc.data());
        })
        this.users = usersArray;
      });
 }
```

---

Now, to be complete, it seems that in this page you just want to display the profile of one user. So you should probably not use `<li v-for="(user, index) in users" :key="index">` which is used when you loop over several items (i.e. `users` here). But this should probably be the subject of another question.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It did resolve the previous error message, but now I am getting a new error: **Error in created hook: "TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__firebase_init__.a.firestore is not a function"** Just so we are clear, in my init.js file, I DID remember to enter `import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/firestore';` which is supposed to solve this problem. I also tried to run Npm Run Dev again to refresh the project on localhost, but that error is still there.